# RoR | Devise redirect loop because of cancan authorize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

Hers is my application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "You must first login to view this page"
    session[:user_return_to] = request.url
    redirect_to "/users/sign_in"
  end                                                                                                                                                  

end
```

This will redirect the use to the login page if the AccessDenied is throw and the user is not logged in ("works nicely"), but once logged in it will cause a redirect loop if logged in but not authorized by cancan since the login page will just redirect them back to the user right back via session[:user_return_to] = request.url.

The question is: how do I handle this logic if the user is logged in but not authorized.

Comment: if you use devise for authentication you can check `current_user` if the user is logged in or not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added a little condition to make this work.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

    #Redirects to login for secure resources
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|

      if user_signed_in?
        flash[:error] = "Not authorized to view this page"
        session[:user_return_to] = nil
        redirect_to root_url

      else              
        flash[:error] = "You must first login to view this page"
        session[:user_return_to] = request.url
        redirect_to "/users/sign_in"
      end 

    end 
end
```